# What is the best/optimized way to bind click event in DOM body except the box as shown in figure?

Tags: javascript, jquery

** What is the best/optimized way to bind click event in DOM body except the box as shown in figure ?**

[image]

**HTML code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
<style>
   body{background-color: rgb(251, 251, 103); padding: 50px 0 0 200px;width:500px; height 400px }
   .header,.body{border:3px solid black; width:400px; background-color:    #fff}
   .header{height:60px; }
   .body{border:3px solid blue; height:300px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div class="body"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: @guest271314 i hv added html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming, the box you want to do detection on is `#box`, then you could do that like this:

```
$(document.body).on("click", function(event) {
    var closest = $(event.target).closest("#box");
    if (!closest.length) {
        console.log("click outside box");
    }
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/amzn7q4w/

Here's a plain Javascript version:

```
function closestParentId(start, id) {
    var found;
    while (start && start !== document.documentElement && !(found = (start.id === id))) {
        start = start.parentNode;
    }
    return found ? start : null;
}


document.body.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var closest = closestParentId(event.target, "box"); 
    if (!closest) {
        log("click outside box");
    }
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/q15rfryL/

Comment: Thanks jfriend00 it's work..... but could be better if you give me core javascript solution.

Comment: @Saeed - What do you mean "core javascript solution"?  You tagged your question as jQuery.

Comment: @jfriednd00- Actually, i have to place this code in two codebases and one of them  i don't have jQuery support

Comment: @Saeed - I added a plain Javascript version.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$(document).on("click", "body:not(.container)", function(e){
   if(!$(e.target).hasClass("container")){
      alert("clicked");
   };
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pvezL7ga/)